# Why is SafeArrayTypeMismatchException being thrown?

Tags: c#

I want to get the current working directory using pinvoke, nothing else, so I chose to add `GetCurrentDirectory` which I wrote like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DefaultDllImportSearchPaths(DllImportSearchPath.System32)]
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetCurrentDirectory(int bufferLength, [Out] char[] buffer);
```

This works just fine but wanted to change the `char[] buffer` to something else, I know `System.Text.StringBuilder` works but really wanted to try making something myself so, as a test, I created:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class CharCollection
{
    public CharCollection(int size)
    {
        _value = new char[size];
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //converts _value to string and removes all ctrl chars and unused chars.
    }

    internal string ToString(int startIndex, uint trueLength)
    {
        //converts _value to string starting from startIndex and the length of trueLength
    }

    internal char[] _value;
}
```

and changed `char[] buffer` to `CharCollection buffer`, but it doesn't work, a `SafeArrayTypeMismatchException` is thrown and I don't understand why. Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Did you also write your own `GetCurrentDirectory` function that would accept such a class? You can't just change the parameter type on only one side

Comment: @UnholySheep not sure what you mean by that. If you didn't understand how it would be after the change it would be like this: `public static extern uint GetCurrentDirectory(int bufferLength, [Out] CharCollection buffer);`. Note that this should work because I did try adding to `_value` in `CharCollection`: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1000)]` and it worked just fine, had to set `bufferLength` in `GetCurrentDirectory` to 1000 because the array's `SizeConst` is equal to 1000 but, it worked non the less. But, after removing `SizeConst` it started to throw the exception again.